# What is the difference between file system filter drivers and file system minifilter drivers? (windows)

Tags: windows, filesystems, kernel, driver, minifilter

Is there a difference between file system filter drivers and file system minifilter drivers? maybe I'm confusing with filesystem legacy filter driver?
I know it's a very big question to ask but any help would be appreciated

Comment: file system filter driver direct attach self to device stack, process IRP, etc. minifilter driver interact with *fltmgr.sys* which is file system filter driver. it not attach self to device stack, and not direct process IRP. but use interface and callbacks with *fltmgr.sys*

Comment: for instance minifilter support safe unload at any time, while full filter driver - no.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem filters are just legacy filters and use the WDM model where you have your DeviceObject and attach to the FS stack while the minifilters use the Filter Manager infrastructure to filter filesystem requests.
Filter Manager itself is a legacy filter or as you call it a filesystem filter driver.